# Bluetooth headphones quality gets bad when joining discord call

Tags: linux, audio, debian, bluetooth

I just installed herstluftwm on my debian machine and configured some stuff when my friends called me on discord. I was listening to music and the sound quality dropped drastically when I joined the call. I was checking `bluetoothctl` and noticed that the headphones switched to "idle" mode when joining the call.
Before joining the call:

```
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_12_2F_E4_A6_A4/sep1/fd0 State: active
```

After joining the call:

```
[CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_12_2F_E4_A6_A4/sep1/fd0 State: active
```

And when I left it went back to "active". Does anybody has an idea why this happens? I also restarted the bluetooth service, re-connected and re-paired the headphones.

---

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I also use a separate microphone so it would be no problem if the mic from the headphone does not work.

Comment: Bluetooth Hands-free Profile sucks. Buy a gaming headset with proprietary wireless instead.

Comment: @DanielB I have a really good gaming headset but the sound just isn't as good as the sound from my headphones.

Comment: Bluetooth sucks the moment you use it for calls rather than just audio output. Either use a separate microphone or a proper headset.

Comment: *Does anybody has an idea why this happens?* Pretty much everybody that has been using Bluetooth audio for the past 20 years or about.

Comment: @Mokubai Forgot to mention, I got a separate microphone and in discord it is selected as input.

Comment: If the headset microphone truly was not activated (this is the trigger), your sound quality would not degrade. Make double-check to make sure everything is set up correctly. (Maybe the output device is relevant, too?)

Comment: @Joda then discord or something else in your operating system is badly written and opens *all* microphone devices and thus switches your headset into handsfree mode. Try some other applications, if they work for using a different microphone while giving good quality audio then you know that discord is the problem.

Comment: @Mokubai that was a good point. Just tested it and it is the same with every app that is accessing my mic, but I am sure that there is a solution, its just not found yet.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205749/how-permanently-remove-or-disable-hsp-hfp-bluetooth-profile

Comment: @Mokubai I really appreciate your help but what is said in the article actually made it worse... my whole audio now sounds like when I was joining a discord call, it is horrible.

Comment: Not an article but a Q&A in a sister site. It has multiple answers. Which one you tried exactly?

Comment: @ChanganAuto The first and the second one, also both together and between the steps I always restarted the services.